# Laravel - Filter using data from url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple question i've been using django and now i moved to laravel and i stuck in this for 2 days

i have form on the index page that will send input to job search page

i used to do like that in django but here its not working

```
public function job_search(Request $request) {
    $keyword = $request->get('keywords');
    $location = $request->get('location');

    if ($keyword) {
        $jobs = Job::where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');

        if ($location) {
            $jobs = Job::where('location', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
        }

    }

    if ($location) {
        $jobs = Job::where('location', 'like', '%'.$location.'%');
    }

    return view('jobs.job_search', compact('jobs','keyword','location'));
}
```

Comment: You're not retrieving any results. Add `->get()` after your `where`.

Comment: thank you ser next time please make an answer to get votes

Answer (score 3):

For **get()**, you retrieve all the rows that fit the where clauses. (Please note that loops are required to access all the rows or you have get some errors).
if you looking for specific data as in a where clause: **Model::where('field', '=', 'value')->get();**

 your are not using ->get()

```
  public function job_search(Request $request) {
        $keyword = $request->get('keywords');
        $location = $request->get('location');

        if ($keyword) {
            $jobs = Job::where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();

            if ($location) {
                $jobs = Job::where('location', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();
            }

        }

        if ($location) {
            $jobs = Job::where('location', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')->get();
        }

        return view('jobs.job_search', compact('jobs','keyword','location'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are having the problem of not adding `->get()` at the end. You are just building the query. With that in mind your code should be:

```
$jobs = Job::where('location', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are overwritting jobs result if both keywords and location present. try like this

```
public function job_search(Request $request) {
$keyword = $request->keywords;
$location = $request->location;
$q = new Job;
if ($keyword) {
    $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
}
if ($location) {
    $q->where('location', 'like', '%'.$location.'%');
}
$jobs = $q->get();
return view('jobs.job_search', compact('jobs','keyword','location'));
}
```

Comment: I would accept this answer as the correct one as it explains a little bit better than mine and ges you a cleaner code